# Protocol Buffer Field Fails to Serialize, Ends Up as Null

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm using Google Protobuf 3.17.3.

```
PS C:\Users\Name> protoc --version
libprotoc 3.17.3
```

I'm running into an issue where, upon serialization of a given object, I'm finding that a field that is non-null is **not** being serialized. I know this because, when the proto-message gets to the server-side, it's fields are null despite being non-null on the client-side.

For example, in the code snippet below, while `Google.Protobuf.ExchangeProto.Update`'s `UpdateNewOrder` field is non-null, after desterilizing this field on the server-side, it ends up as null. The `UpdateType` field serializes just fine.

```cs
        public async Task SendNewOrderAsync(NewOrder newOrder)
        {
            var networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            {
                using var gms = new Google.Protobuf.CodedOutputStream(ms);
                var update = new Google.Protobuf.ExchangeProto.Update()
                {
                    UpdateType = Google.Protobuf.ExchangeProto.Update.Types.UpdateType.NewOrder,
                    UpdateNewOrder = ProtoAdapter.NewOrderToProto(newOrder), // < -- Problematic field!
                };
                update.WriteTo(gms);
            }
            await networkStream.WriteAsync(ms.ToArray());
        }
```

It appears this isn't a server-side problem, though. I noticed post-serialization on the client-side, that the underlying `MemoryStream` object is particularly small (only 27 bytes).

**Client Side Memory Stream Object Details**

[image]

**Server Side Object Post-Parse - Missing UpdateNewOrder Field**

[image]

`ProtoAdapter` is where the to-and-from proto logic resides. This particular `NewOrderToProto` message looks as such:

```cs
        public static Google.Protobuf.ExchangeProto.NewOrder NewOrderToProto(NewOrder newOrder)
        {
            return new Google.Protobuf.ExchangeProto.NewOrder()
            {
                Symbol = newOrder.Symbol,
                IsBuy = newOrder.IsBuy,
                OrderId = newOrder.OrderID,
                Price = newOrder.Price,
                Quantity = newOrder.Quantity,
            };
        }
```

The update message I'm attempting to serialize looks like the following:

```proto
message Update
{
    enum UpdateType
    {
        UpdateType_NewOrder = 0;
        UpdateType_CancelOrder = 1;
    }

    UpdateType update_type = 1;
    NewOrder update_new_order = 2;
    CancelOrder update_cancel_order = 3;
}
```

The struct that isn't serializing properly in the `Update` message's `update_new_order` field looks like such:

```proto
message NewOrder
{
    string symbol = 1;
    int32 quantity = 2;
    int64 price = 3;
    bool is_buy = 4;
    uint64 order_id = 5;
}
```

**Question:** Why is the `UpdateNewOrder` field not being serialized?

Answer (score 1):

So I looked into this, and started playing around with the order of operations on the server-side. The issue wasn't on the client-side. I found that out by deserializing the message on the client-side right after serializing it, noticing that the `UpdateNewOrder` field is non-null, exactly what I need to rule out a client-side issue.

I then started playing with the server-side, and noticed that the Parser's ParseFrom method can take in any object that inherits from stream, but seems to work best when passing in a CodedInputStream as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Your `MemoryStream` looks pretty useless, can't you just pass `byteArray` and `numBytesRead` to the CodedInputStream constructor?

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, it's useless, edited my answer to only use `CodedInputStream` and `byteArray`, removing the `MemoryStream`.